# What exactly is a "library" in a crate?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm a little confused about the concept "library" in rust, which is mentioned from "A crate is a binary or library".

If I'm right, a binary means an executable program (which can be run from shell, for example), but what is a library?

Are they some sort of object files with symbols like .a or .so, which will be linked to my program (like C/C++)

Or they are pure source codes which will be compiled together with my program?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As described by Masklinn, yes, Rust does have prebuilt library formats. However, these are mostly used internally, are finnicky for different compiler versions, and [cargo still lacks support for them](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/1139). In fact, crates.io requires libraries to be "open-source" (as in, you provide the source code, you could still have the source code load from some closed-source dependency), and it distributes the source code to whoever downloads the crate. Then, the source code is effectively compiled with your program (this is where rlibs come in to play, but cargo doesn't expose this to the user). This is also why you're able to inspect the source code for pretty much every crate.

Comment: Do you suggest that even though source codes and prebuilt format are both supported, currently most crates use source codes?

Comment: I suggest that source code is the **only** well-supported format and that prebuilt crates are pretty much only used internally by cargo, and the **vast majority** of crates (including everything on crates.io) has source code to some degree.

Answer (score 1):

> If I'm right, a binary means an executable program (which can be run from shell, for example), but what is a library?

Yes. Specifically, per [the Linkage documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/linkage.html)

> A runnable executable will be produced. This requires that there is a main function in the crate which will be run when the program begins executing. This will link in all Rust and native dependencies, producing a single distributable binary. This is the default crate type.

> Are they some sort of object files with symbols like .a or .so, which will be linked to my program (like C/C++)
>
> Or they are pure source codes which will be compiled together with my program?

Never strictly the latter, but the exact artefact depends, as per the linkage documentation:

> A Rust library will be produced. This is an ambiguous concept as to what exactly is produced because a library can manifest itself in several forms. The purpose of this generic lib option is to generate the "compiler recommended" style of library. The output library will always be usable by rustc, but the actual type of library may change from time-to-time.

The documentation then lists the various types of libraries:

- rlib, a static library with rust-specific metadata (an augmented .a)
- dylib, a dynamic library with rust-specific metadata (an augmented .so)
- staticlib, a system static library (an actual .a)
- cdylib, a system dynamic library (an actual .so)

I would think "lib" aliases to "rlib" but frankly I have no idea, and as the quote notes that's neither fixed nor documented *by design*.

Comment: It seems that the no matter what the form is, a library is not consist of source codes, right? But why I can jump into some libraries I import to check the code? Is this done by cargo if it can find the source code of the library?